# Is it possible to compile and run an Xcode project on a jailbroken device without a paid developer certificate?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, xcode, ios

Both for kicks and for budgetary reasons, I'd like to take a package that would normally require a developer account and build an app to run on a jailbroken iOS device.

I have a 5th gen iPod Touch, jailbroken using evasi0n, running iOS 6.1.

I am using Xcode 4.6 with OS X (10.8.2) Lion.

Answer (score 6):

The following instructional steps to accomplish this purpose are taken from:
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode

My findings and actions are provided under each step.

**1. Create a self-signed code-signing certificate with the name “iPhone Developer” on the “login” (default) keychain using Keychain Access.**

- I took screenshots as I followed the above instruction.
- I left most fields blank or at their default value.

[image]

**2. Open `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist` (4.2 or below: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist`). You may need root permission.**

- I'm using Xcode 4.6, so I opened the former `.plist` file.

**3. Replace all occurrences of `XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext` by `XCCodeSignContext`. There are three of them (XCode Version 3.2.4+).**

- I made three modifications as the screenshots indicate.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**4. Save the file and restart Xcode.**

- Saved the file.

**5. Make sure you have ldid on your Mac. Place a copy somewhere e.g. in `/usr/local/bin`.**

- I downloaded ldid from http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid
- I put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

**6. Create the a Python script ldid3.py right next to the ldid program. Make it executable. Fill it with:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from subprocess import check_call
from os.path import basename, dirname, splitext, join
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

app = argv[-1]
ldid_path = join(dirname(__file__), 'ldid')
obj_path = join(app, splitext(basename(app))[0])

if '-gta' not in argv:
    check_call([ldid_path, '-S', obj_path])
else:
    with NamedTemporaryFile('w+b', 0) as f:
        f.write("""
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
        """)
        check_call([ldid_path, '-S' + f.name, obj_path])
```

- I created a new plain text file and copy-pasted the above code into it.
- I saved this file as `ldid3.py` and stored it in the `/usr/local/bin` directory.
- In terminal, ran `chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/ldid3.py`.

**7. Open `iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec`. This file can be found in [For Xcode 4.6: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec`]:**

**8. Change the entry in the file from calling `codesign` to `ldid3.py`.**

- As per instruction official instruction, converted the spec file to plain text by typing in console: `sudo plutil -convert xml1 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec`
- I opened the file with TextEdit.
- Replaced `<key>CommandLine</key><string>/usr/bin/codesign</string>` with `<key>CommandLine</key><string>/usr/local/bin/ldid3.py</string>`.

**9. Save the file and restart Xcode.**

- I saved the file and quit TextEdit.

**10. Create a file `/var/mobile/tdmtanf` on the device, to enable Apple's "TDMTANF bypass" in installd (warning: doing so will also put you in a sandboxed GameCenter).**

- I create an empty text file in Windows, named it `tdmtanf`, SSH'd into my iPod, uploaded it to `/var/mobile/`, and reboot my iPod.

### Now that all that is over with...

I open my existing Xcode project and hit Run. It works in the iOS Simulator without any problems.

[image]

I make sure that Code Signing is set to use the certificate set up in step 1.

[image]

I build the app (Project > Build). A success message follows.

I grab my app folder `TicTacToe.app` from `/Libary/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TicTacToe-cjgzmoxtflyegtfypsbxbuiuwxns/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/` and transfer it to my Windows machine to install onto my iPod.

In an attempt to install the app to my iPod, I drag `TicTacToe.app` onto the applications section of iPhone Configuration Utility, but I received this error message saying that my app "is not a valid mobile application."

I have also tried manually installing the app using **[iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/)** and the **AppCake** app found in Cydia. Both fail.

[image]
[image]

As a point of interest, because as I've Googled around, I've noticed many people mention the importance of this: I do have AppSync installed. (Sorry for the huge screenshot. If I should take it down, please let me know!)

[image]

### Conclusion

So despite following the instructions closely, several times, my app is not recognized by iPhone Configuration Utility as a valid app. I cannot install the app manually using programs like iFunbox, or Cydia apps like AppCake.

I suspect the app is indeed invalid, but having followed the instructions carefully, I'm not sure why.

Can anyone tell me why my app is not valid, and what I can do to fix this, besides coughing up money that is?

Comment: It was an interesting reading, though.

Comment: Nope - glad to have read it and will probably return to it in the future. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: [This](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-ios-401/) was very helpful to me when working on Xcode 4.2 and iOS 4, I hope someone can update the procedure to Xcode 4.6

Comment: After downloading ldid you need to change its permissions to 755 with chmod 755 ldid. This was causing me an exit 1 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your device and select your iOS Device as Run target. when its run, the application automatically installed on your device.
Or you can select your iOS Device, then no need to Run just Build and Archive it. After that, distribute... choose Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment. You'll get your .ipa file. 
Hope it can help you..

Answer (score 0):

continuing @joncom s answer.. you can add the .app files to your iPhone directly, just with a few extra steps.

- copy the `.app` file onto your desktop, and then zip it
- rename the `[yourappname].zip` to `[yourappname].ipa`
- then go ahead and download AppSync from cydia
- download and install the .ipa file onto your device

NOTE:

you can also do this directly without going through all the python code modification the @joncom mentioned.. read more [here](http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/12/26/build-ipa-file-using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/)